# Is it possible to change the color of only one dot in a scatter plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

So this is my code currently,

```
import random
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

x = random.randint(1, 100)
i = 0
tries = []
z = 0

while True:
    i+=1
    y = random.randint(1, 100)
    tries.append(y)
    if y==x:
        y=z
        print(f"The computer got it right in {i} tries.")
        print(f"The number was {x}")
        break

print(tries)
mpl.plot(tries, tries, 'o')
mpl.show()
```

So it's about getting the computer to guess a random number, putting all the attempts in a list, and plotting all the attempts in a scatter plot. So is it possible to change the color of only the correct attempt in the graph, and having the rest all be default?

I tried to store the all the points on the x-axis and y-axis in a numpy array but it changes the color of all of the dots, and not only one dot.

Comment: `mpl.plot(x, x, 'o', color='red')`?

Comment: You can plot two times: first all dots, and on top you only plot the dot with the different color.

Comment: When using `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` you can supply keyword arg `c` with a list of colors for each point. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) for mor information.

Comment: (As an aside, importing `matplotlib.pyplot as mpl` instead of `as plt` can lead to quite some confusion when comparing your code with only examples.  `mpl` is often how `matplotlib` is imported.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can.

To achieve this, you need to handle the plotting of that specific point separately from the others.

**Plotting All Guesses Except the Last One**

```
mpl.plot(tries[:-1], tries[:-1], 'o', color='blue')
```

tries[:-1]: This is a slicing operation on the tries list. It selects all elements of the list except the last one

**Plotting the Last Guess with a Different Color**

```
mpl.plot(tries[-1], tries[-1], 'o', color='red')
```

tries[-1]: This time, the code uses negative indexing to select only the last element of the tries list.

Full code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl


x = random.randint(1, 100)
i = 0
tries = []

while True:
    i += 1
    y = random.randint(1, 100)
    tries.append(y)
    if y == x:
        print(f"The computer got it right in {i} tries.")
        print(f"The number was {x}")
        break

# Plot the wrong guesses blue
mpl.plot(tries[:-1], tries[:-1], 'o', color='blue')

# Plot the right guess in red
mpl.plot(tries[-1], tries[-1], 'o', color='red')

mpl.show()
```